# View entire Mac OSX iso under Windows

Tags: macos

I have a ISO of my OEM Mac Disc, which I would like to do something with. However, whenever I mount it, I only see the bootcamp "side" of the disc. Even when I extract the image I can't find the actualy Mac install files. How do I view them?I've searched everywhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't search *everywhere*. Besides, please tell us what you want to do. This sounds a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: What exactly is this "something"?

Comment: I would like to modify an install file. Okay, I haven't searched everywhere, I have looked hard. Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Notifying @slhck -- Just do that on your Mac that came with said OEM DVD?

Comment: It needs a new Hard Drive and that isn't going to be here for atleast another 2 weeks.

Comment: You can probably [read from the disk image](http://catacombae.org/hfsx.html), give it a shot.